# Restore folder from lnk

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file

Some virus has named all the folders in the usb flash disk to foldername.lnk (the folder named games has been changed to games.lnk).Properties of the flash drive shows size of the folder as the disk space used.How do I restore the folder with batch file or vbscript?

Comment: This question is unanswerable.  Please provide more detail.

Comment: What virus are you referring to?

Comment: I do not remember the name as it got deleted after virus scan.There were files in the folder of the usb disk.Now the folders have become shortcuts.Opening command prompt and typing dir results in file names as games.lnk,soft.lnk,pdffiles.lnk

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file and write this

```
attrib -h -s -r \s \d
```

this will change attributes of all files and folders at current directory

---

**Update:**

The following `vbScript` will rename all folders having extension like `folder_name.someExtension` and make them with previous names.

**create 2 files:**
1. script.vbs
2. rename.bat

**script.vbs**

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = objFS.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)

For Each Folder In objFolder.SubFolders
   Folder.Name=Mid(Folder.Name,1,InStrRev(Folder.Name,".")-1)
Next
```

**rename.bat**

```
cscript /nologo script.vbs
```

Place them is same folder where changed folder are. And run the `rename.bat` file.

and That's it.
Enjoy :)

Comment: I can see all the files so by typing the attrib command will not help.One way of explaining is that if I use the following command

Comment: ren "Soft" "Soft.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}",the folder named "Soft" becomes a shortcut to Control panel.When I click on "Soft" control panel opens.Similarly my folders have become shortcuts to exes in the root of the same drive but the exe does not exist

Comment: All Folders are converted to Control panel link only or different types like My computer, recycle bin etc? It will be better If a Print Screen image is ADDED....

Comment: Control panel link was just an example of my problem.I had folders named Games,Softwares,photos and clips.Its properties showed as folders.Now these folders properties show as "SHortcut".The drive letter is H.On dir command I now get Games.lnk, Softwares.lnk, Photos.lnk and clips.lnk.Your script has no effect because the it is not the name of the folder that has changed but it is the property of the folder that has changed.Folder is become a shortcut,similar to a folder shortcut being created(right click the folder and select Create Shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

Using "attrib -h -s -r \s \d" 
immediately did the trick for me, except for one thing. 
The backslashes ( \ ) should both be forward slashes ( / )
So

```
attrib -h -s -r /s /d
```

But nontheless, many thanks to the original poster of the solution, because it really helped me.
I just thought i'd point it out for other people who might need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Take it easy,,,with easiest Steps :-

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Open Folder Options
3. Go to "View" tab there
4. Sub Menu> Hidden Files and Folders
5. Tick the option i.e: Show hidden files and folders
6. Apply and Click Ok
7. Now Be Back to Hard Drive Containing Folders of .lnk extensions
8. There you will see your original folders (dim lightning)
9. Delete files/folders with .lnk extensions
10. and enjoy with your original folders....!

Hope this Helps...:-)

Answer (score 0):

The Folders attributes must have been changed to `Hidden+System+Readonly`. Delete the links. And enable `"View Hidden Files"` and `"View System Files"` to view your folders.

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry but I have not downvoted you